# How can I get the top 100 Freebase films ranked by "popularity"?

Tags: freebase, freebase-acre

I basically just want a list of "big time movies"....

I'm not sure which property to use for this - I tried the gross_revenue fields but they all seem to come back blank:

```
[{
 "type": "/film/film",
 "limit": 100,
 "name": null,
 "id": null,
 "/common/topic/image": {
 "id": null,
 "limit": 1
},
"gross_revenue": null
}]
```

Any thoughts from any Freebase experts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expected type for the gross revenue property is a dated monetary value, so it has not only a number, but a currency and a date associated with it.  Even if it had a number, your original query wouldn't return the top 100 because it's not sorting them, so you're just getting the first 100 random films.

This [query](http://tinyurl.com/nr4e4vd) will give you the 100 films with the largest number for gross revenue value, **without** taking into account currency or inflation:

```
[{
  "type": "/film/film",
  "limit": 100,
  "name": null,
  "id": null,
  "/common/topic/image": {
    "id": null,
    "limit": 1
  },
  "gross_revenue": [{
    "amount": null,
    "currency": null,
    "valid_date": null
  }],
  "sort": "-gross_revenue.amount"
}]
```

Comment: thanks Tom, having plenty of other issues, but that was the right answer for that one, thanks!